# Filter values in data frame

Tags: r, filter, dataset

Basically, I have a gene dataset in which the rows are genes and columns are sequential time points of protein folding. I need a function to filter genes of a certain threshold value from others across the entire data set, not just for certain vectors. For example:

```
          alpha98 alpha105 alpha112 alpha119
YAL002W      0.22     0.58    -0.36     0.13
YAL003W      0.05     0.55    -0.08     0.33
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: df[df$alpha98>threshold,] ?

Comment: do you want the threshold applied to all genes, or just to a specific kind?   If the gene exceeds the threshold, do you want to select the whole row or just that particular value?

Comment: Thanks, juba. I was wondering if there was a way to do this for the entire data set, not just the columns. I will specify this.

Comment: Ricardo, thanks for your suggestion for me to specify. I'm seeking a function that's applicable for the entire data set, not just for a particular vector.

Comment: @user2105555, then as Juba points out, you can simply use `myDF[myDF>threshold]` (without specifying a column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R` is vectorized and `R` recycles.  That means, that generally, something as simple as `myDF > threshold` will get you awfully close to what you need.

Specifically, it will give you a logical `matrix` of the same dimensions as your `data.frame` which will be `TRUE` when that cell in the DF exceeds the threshold (and `FALSE` otherwise).

You can then use that matrix as your tool to subset the data.frame.

```
myDF[myDF > threshold]
```