# How to filter numeric values in Pandas not in Boolean values, but in a new column with filtered integers?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset and a column with numeric values. In order to apply a log function to the column, I need to filter negative and zero values first. How can I create a new column (or a variable) with non-Boolean values? If I apply `data['new_column'] = (data['old_column'] > 0)` I can only get Boolean values which are useful for me further.

I assume my question is quite similar to the ones below, but I don't know how to transfer R syntax to Python.

[How to efficiently filter a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106330/how-to-efficiently-filter-a-data-frame)
[Filter values in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867337/filter-values-in-data-frame)
[How to filter out data out of a dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586176/how-to-filter-out-data-out-of-a-dataset)